# "Give it to me please" or "give it me please"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm not sure if I have to add the preposition "**to**" in the following sentence. Do I have?

> "Give it **to** me please"

or

> "give it me please"

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most relatively formal dialects, the **to** is essential. In casual usage in some dialects, the *to* is extraneous and may sound wrong. If you were to analyse the latter sort of dialect properly, I suspect you would say that the *to* is implicit in *give*.